# error: 'OneSignal/OneSignal.h' file not found #import <OneSignal/OneSignal.h>

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, onesignal

Using OneSignal (2.6.0) pod successfully installed but it gives error file not found in bridging header file xcode - 9.3,swift 4.1

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

download OneSignal ios sdk from github repository & copy OneSignal.framework from it to my project...clean & build it solved both errors

installing it using pods , header files not found in pod OneSignal.framework

Comment: could you specify which from directory/file to the exact target location?

Answer (score 1):

For me work doing

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
pod repo update
```

Also then you should reinstall your one signal library, if you are using cordova:

```
cordova plugin rm onesignal-cordova-plugin
cordova plugin add onesignal-cordova-plugin --save
```

Answer (score 0):

This error means the framework is not present in your project folder:

- Try to clean your project : cmd + shift + k
- Try to reinstall your library.

If it still doesn't work, try deleting your pod folder (keep your podfile) and rerun `pod install`

Comment: same  error came & also gives error like                                     <unknown>:0: error: failed to emit precompiled header '.pch' for bridging header 'Bridging-Header.h'

Comment: Ok, did you have a look to the GitHub of that library, if there is any issue opened on that subject? like that one: https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-iOS-SDK/issues/271

Comment: while installing pods file was not found Instead of this I'm adding framework from github repository example ...it's build success

Comment: using OneSignal with pods not display any header files ...it's the problem with pods directly from github ?